# Need to use sudo su - in Unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix, sudo, su

I am at beginner level and I need to use `sudo su -` and `pwd` in one command line in script for two different users.  (I'm using `pwd` as an example; the specific command is not important.) 
And I am using command `sudo su - user -c pwd`. This command works when switching to one user, but not when switching to another.

For example:-

```
$ sudo su - ora -c pwd
/oracle/
$ sudo su - adm -c pwd
Sorry, user myuser is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/su - adm -c pwd' as root on server.
$
```

How can I make it work for 'adm' user too?

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  Establish the home directory for users `ora` and `adm`?  If so, this isn't how you do it: `echo ~ora ~adm` should do the job.  As for why it is failing, you're going to need to look (hard) at the `/etc/sudoers` configuration file.

Comment: I don't think this is a good approach. In general, you write your script assuming it's running as the appropriate user. Then you can just `sudo` to that user (and add the appropriate entry in the sudoers file) for that one script.

Comment: The second user (the one that doesn't work) is a sudoer user ? Because not all users are sudoers, meaning that not all users can make sudo su. Take a look over this blog [Take Control of your Linux](http://www.garron.me/en/linux/visudo-command-sudoers-file-sudo-default-editor.html)

Comment: No, its just an example its not about pwd, its not allowing me to run any command `sudo su - adm -c anycommand`..

Comment: You'll need to scrutinize your `/etc/sudoers` file, then.  It appears to allow you to switch to `ora`, but not to `adm`; it's kinda odd since it allows you to become root.  You might try: `sudo sh -c "su - adm -c pwd"` and see whether that gets you anywhere.

Comment: Thanks Elliott Frisch, But for one user its excuting command and not for other. when I do `sudo su - adm` I am able to switch user and able to run command but when i use command `sudo su - adm -c command` its not working

Comment: Also, have you checked any other users — is `ora` the exception in being allowed, or is `adm` the exception in being rejected?  Or is it a mixed bag?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan Leffler, I think /etc/sudoers file is already scrutinized as i am able to do `sudo su - adm`..but unable to use as `sudo su - adm -c command`. thanks to help

Comment: sorry I didnt get u properly Jonathan..I am able to execute `sudo su - ora -c command` but not `sudo su - adm -c command`. Thanks

Comment: OK; you've scrutinized `/etc/sudoers`; we can't, which makes it kinda frustrating to try helping you.  Since `sudo` is implementing the controls, we need to see what its control file says to deduce why you're seeing the behaviour you're seeing. It might also be something to do with a difference in the password file or shadow password file entries for the two users.  Which platform are you on?  While these things are similar, maybe you have SE Linux, which might change things more.  But, with the information currently provided, we cannot help — we'll have to close the question as unanswerable.

Comment: I gave you a different command line to execute.  Did you try it?  Can you read what my alternative said? Can you see how it is different from what you are trying but failing to execute?

Comment: Platform is AIX 6.1, I am not at expert level and dont have any idea for password file or shadow password file. thanks to assit.
command `sudo sh -c "su - adm -c pwd"` is not working for both the user `adm` and `ora`..Thanks

Comment: I can provide you the things what u ask for..

Answer (score 0):

sudo is used to run a command as somebody else.
By default it runs a command as root.
You can also supply the -u  option to run a command as another user.
You really shouldn't need to use sudo and su together as they do similar jobs.
Sudo does this job in a much more controlled and configurable fashion.

Sudo can be configured to control:

- Who can use it.
- What commands they can run.
- Who they can run them as.
- Whether they need to supply their password when doing so.

You can only run one command at a time, so if you need to do several things together you will need to write a script.  Alternatively you can chain them together in a one liner.  Or finally you can run a shell as the user you require.  e.g.:

```
sudo bash
```

I think in your case you probably want to use:

```
sudo -u adm anycommand
```