# How to obtain a list of SID's on a machine in Java Application

Tags: java, oracle, sid

I am attempting to look up the list of SID's on a host. I have the host, port, username and password for Oracle and I want to find out the SID's on the machine.

I am able to logon to the machine and use "lsnrctl status" to return the SID's however when I try to run this through my java application it is unsuccessful. This is due to the Oracle version:

> From 10g oracle default has Security ON: Local OS Authentication
>   meaning that only the local OS user that started the listener can
>   issue lsnrctl commands to the listener. The listener will refuse to
>   answer any other user.

Comment: I am unsure of how to do this. Creating a JDBC session in my java application now and going to see what I can get from that - any suggestions would help!

Comment: My apologies to the poster and J. Chomel.  Of course you are looking for ORACLE_SID.  You can find these in $ORATAB which can usually be found in /etc/oratab or /var/opt/oracle/oratab.  Sorry - complete brain freeze on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this. You can give the listener a password which allows the listener to talk to users who are authenticated via Local OS Authentication or via the password - my java application can use the password to authenticate by passing the password as part of the STATUS connect_data.

Source: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_listener_password_security_lsnrctl.htm

Answer (score 1):

If the user that runs the application is not able to do what you want, then you should have

- a little [`cron` job](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job) export the result of `lsnrctl status` to a file every now and then
- read this file from your java application

Another solution would be to allow the java Unix user to do this command, e.g. with [`sudo -u oracle lsnrctl status`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23733720/6019417); this require a little research on how `su` works, or some manipulation from your sysadmin.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for confusion between ORACLE_SID and Session ID (SID).

ORACLE_SID is in $ORATAB which is usually found in /etc/oratab or /var/opt/oracle/oratab.

Comment: Aren't you confusing Session Ids with [ORACLE_SID](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORACLE_SID)?

Comment: It seems he wants oracle SID?  If he wants process ID, then it's also there in that script.  Not sure what other session ID there is?

Comment: Oracle's System IDs on a server is a list of databases running on this server; it is something different from the current databases' processes ID you'll get from this query.